# Windows .exe file icon changes when file name is changed?

Tags: windows, java, icons, filenames

I'm making a program in Java. After I make the program and compile it into a .jar file, I wrap it in a .exe file (yes, I know this defeats the purpose of cross-platform but I am most comfortable with Java and this is mainly a Windows program). Now, when I choose my .ico in the wrapper program, Launch4J, the file it outputs has a squished icon. But, if I change the file name to anything but the file name I want it to be, the icon fixes itself without me doing anything other than changing the file name. This happens even if I change the name after the .exe has been generated. Why is this happening and is there any way to fix this?

Edit: After trying different file locations, I also noticed that the icon looks fine everywhere but a folder. Desktop looks fine, alt+tab looks fine, systray, and the bar at the bottom where you can click the program (forgot what it's called) all look fine. It's just in windows explorer it looks funny.

Edit: For solution, look at Werner Henze's comment on this post!

Comment: Probably borderline, but I would think it more probable you´ll get an answer in stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JannisAlexakis No. This question is not about programming. If I would see this question on SO I would migrate it here.

Comment: You could try rebuilding the Shell Icon Cache: http://superuser.com/a/160256/220983 and http://superuser.com/a/50385/220983