# Windows 7 generic icon over normal icon

Tags: windows-7, icons, desktop-icons

I have a problem with one windows 7 machine. If I logged in, I can see any generic icons. But under the generic icon is the normal icon of the program.

I tried to delete the IconCache.db and set the screen bit depth to 16 and then back to 32. But nothing change.

To delete the IconCache.db I use the following command:

```
del %userprofile%\appdata\local\iconcache.db /a:h
```

Does anyone has another solution to solve the problem?

[image]

**Solution for me:**

Registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE – SOFTWARE – Microsoft – 
Windows – CurrentVersion – Explorer – Shell Icons
```

Add 'New String Value' with name: `29` and the value `%windir%\System32\shell32.dll,-50`

Comment: This means the regular icon has another icon overlayed, but that overlay is broken somehow. Please see this question and let us know if that answer helps you: https://superuser.com/questions/50363/desktop-icons-corrupted-in-windows-7-how-do-i-fix-this?rq=1

Comment: This was the solution with the arrow icon (overlay). The arrow icon was damaged and the result was the overlaid generic icon.